# Filed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: django

My images are not loading in a template. I was placing them in admin, so everything should be ok but,no.
Model field

```
class Guide(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = '/trips/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'trips/media/')
```

Project tree

[image]

Template

```
 {% if item.image%}
    <img src="{{item.image.url}}" alt="" style="max-height:300px">
 {%else%}
    <img src="{%static 'avatar_sample.png' %}" id="uploaded_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
 {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you import these settings in urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```